# How to add new route to autogenerate resources?

Tags: go, buffalo

please help me, I want add new route/func to generate resource (etc. users).

```
app.Resource("/users", UsersResource{})
```

I found func addRoute, but doesn't work.

```
func (a *App) addRoute(method string, url string, h Handler) *RouteInfo { ...
```

My idea is something like this.

```
"/users/handleSomething/idOfUser"
```

Right now i have only this func:

```
List(Context)
Show(Context)
New(Context)
Create(Context)
Edit(Context)
Update(Context)
Destroy(Context)
```

Thx for your time and help :)

PS: Sorry for my English :(

Comment: You have generated the resource and need to add a route? Or you need to generate a resource using `buffalo resource generator`?

Comment: I generated the resource "users" with `buffalo resource generator users` and that generated "UserResource", which has these func Create, Show, Update... And what i want is add my new func with route to this "UserResource". I don't want create new Handler, if is this possible. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want additional routes you can use the methods `GET,POST,PUT, ...` that are defined on the `*App` type. (https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/routing#supported-http-methods)

To handle dynamic path segments in the route you can use named parameters. (https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/routing#named-parameters)

Example:

```
app.PATCH("/users/handleSomething/{id}", handleSomethingHandler)
```

To retrieve the value of the named parameter you can use `c.Param("id")` where `c` is the buffalo context passed in to your handler.